# How to get key from the json and preserve the order

Tags: json, kotlin, gson

I have a `JSON` with some `key-value` pairs. I need to pick up by name and process it's value differently. The oder of the process should be same order as the keys listed in the `JSON` (`JSON` is unknown, only knows it will have some key and corresponding value, so cant not know the order outside of the `JSON`).

Simplified sample usage:

```
String jsonData = "{key1:{some other data}, key2:{sub-key:sub-value}}";
val jsonObject = JSONObject(jsonData)
val names = jsonObject.keys()
if (names.hasNext()) {
 val key = names.next()
 val valueJson = jsonData.optString(key)
 val gson = Gson()

 val resultList = ArrayList<Data> () // result should keep the order as the keys in the json
 if (key == "key1") {
  val parsedResult = gson.fromJson <POJO_1> (valueJson, POJO_1::class.java)
  resultList.add(processDataFromKey1(parsedResult))
 } else if (key == "key2") {
  val parsedResult = gson.fromJson <POJO_2> (valueJson, POJO_2::class.java)
  resultList.add(processDataFromKey2(parsedResult))
 }
}
```

The problem is the `jsonObject.keys()` the order of the keys is `undefined`.

So how to preserve the order of the keys from the `JSON` string (don't want to add dependency `javax.json:javax.json-api`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.json.JSONObject` internally uses `HashMap`. They even added some comment to it:

> `HashMap` is used on purpose to ensure that elements are unordered by
>   the specification. `JSON` tends to be a portable transfer format to
>   allows the container implementations to rearrange their items for a
>   faster element retrieval based on associative access. Therefore, an
>   **implementation mustn't rely on the order of the item**.

Use `Gson`. It uses `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap` implementation for `Map`. From it's documentation:

> A map of comparable keys to values. Unlike `TreeMap`, this class
>   uses **insertion** order for iteration order. Comparison order is only
>   used as an optimization for efficient insertion and removal.
>   This implementation was derived from Android 4.1's TreeMap class.

So, for below `JSON` `payload`:

```
{
  "status": "status",
  "date": "01/10/2019",
  "abc": {
    "Field1": "value1",
    "key": "value2"
  },
  "rgj": {
    "key": "value2",
    "Field1": "value3"
  },
  "name": "Rick"
}
```

This example app:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Map;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {
        }.getType();
        Map<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(jsonFile), type);
        map.forEach((k, v) -> {
            if (v instanceof Map) {
                System.out.println(k);
                ((Map) v).forEach((k1, v1) -> System.out.println("   " + k1 + " => " + v1));
            } else {
                System.out.println(k + " => " + v);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
status => status
date => 01/10/2019
abc
   Field1 => value1
   key => value2
rgj
   key => value2
   Field1 => value3
name => Rick
```

Notice that `key` and `Field1` are in different order in `abc` and `rgj` objects.

Comment: thanks @Michał Ziober for the good explanation. two questions: 1.   will the solution work for different/arbitrary type json, meaning if the json starts from a array i.e. json = "[......]" or json="{data: [...]}; 2. any thought about using `com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader(StringReader(jsonStr))`, traverse with checking the JsonToken = reader.peek()? both are loading into a Reader so the performance might be similar.

Comment: `1.` Yes, order in array will be the same as in `JSON`. `2.` Traversing manually will be much complicated but could be faster. If `JSON` is not enormously big it is not worth of it.

Comment: hmm, the json data is large (over a meg is normal case) here. thx!

Answer (score 1):

you could use jsonparser rather than jsonreader so you control the event flow.
See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/stream/JsonParser.html

Note that your question is neither kotlin nor gson specific.

Comment: thanks @cghislai,  it is on android so would like to see if with org.json.JSONObject or Gson (has already dependency on it) could do it.  and dont want add another dependency on "javax.json:javax.json-api:1.1.4"

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do is refer to the String jsonData in your example and rebuild the order.

Something like:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);
Iterator<String> keys = json.keys();
List<KeyOrder> ordering = new ArrayList();
while(keys.hasNext()) {
    String key = keys.next();
    int loc = jsonData.indexOf('"' + key + '"');
    ordering.add(new KeyOrder(loc, key));
}
Collections.sort(ordering);
for(KeyOrder order: ordering) {
    Object value = json.get(order.getKey());
    // process the key and value
}

public class KeyOrder implements Comparable<KeyOrder> {
    private int order;
    private String key;

    public KeyOrder(int order, String key) {
        this.order = order;
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(KeyOrder o) {
        return order - o.getOrder();
    }

    private int getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is based on what to rebuild the order.  dont know what data it will be look like but only know it has key value pair.